# What screen capture apps for OS X exist as alternatives to Fraps?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, games

What is the best alternative to [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/download.php) for the Mac?

What should it do:

- In-game screen capture.
- Record audio from both microphone and system audio at the same time
- Fast
- (Optional) Video compression.
- (Optional) Ability to display framerate (FPS)

Comment: I'd add that the ability to display the framerate is pretty important

Comment: @Daniil Your question is highly likely to be closed, but this can be prevented: move your viable suggestions into answers (maybe not mentioning Krut as you seem to not like it) so people can vote on them individually, and think about removing the "free or cheap" requirement. You can, later, pick a free or cheap option if you like, but others will find the question more useful if it also has answers that cost more.

Comment: @Daniil I've edited your question to fix some minor things, but I've left the content and gist as-is for you to fix as you see fit.

Comment: @CajunLuke, thanks! Removed «free» requirement to make question more useful for other people. Also moved my suggestions into answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions:

- **[iShowU HD](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowu-hd/)** – great app, can record in-game videos, records both microphone and system app, compress video and still fast; $29.95.
- **QuickTime** – records audio only from system input, supports in-game screen capture, slower then iShowU HD, but still smooth, free and built-in.
- **[Krut](http://krut.sourceforge.net/)** – Ugly interface, very buggy.
- **[Screeny](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screeny/id440991524?mt=12)** – No demo available; $14.99

Comment: QuickTime (at least on Mountain Lion) can record audio from any source during screen recording.

Comment: You can select any audio source from within QT: http://d.pr/i/2RpW Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @ALSRubl-Arial yes, you are. It can't record system sound (music, game sounds, etc) and my voice at the same time.